# Why does not ant delete task work?

Tags: java, ant, build

I have this *ant* script:

```
<sequential>
    <echo message="Deleting needed folder" />
    <property name="bigPathToFolder" value="${basePath}/pathToFolder" /> 
    <delete dir="bigPathToFolder" quiet="false"/>
    <echo message="Delete success" />
</sequential>
```

In console I see `Deleting needed folder` and after `Delete success`, but the content of the folder and folder don't change.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have given proper access to the ant file??

Comment: In linux you can check with ls -ltr command

Comment: Follow this - http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7

Comment: Please let us know what it is saying in the console

Comment: *Deleting needed folder* only

Comment: I can delete this folder manually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace

```
<delete dir="bigPathToFolder" quiet="false"/>
```

to

```
<delete dir="${bigPathToFolder}" quiet="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use if task available from ant-contrib to do file existance check at path you are looking & run a delete like below:

```
<if>
        <available file="${bigPathToFolder}"/>
        <then>
           <delete dir="${bigPathToFolder}" quiet="false"/>
           <echo message="Delete success" />
        </then>
        <else>
            <echo message="File Not found at path : ${bigPathToFolder}" />
        </else>
</if>
```